# Adding or updating a record in one function

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

In this function I would like to see if a user with such email has already been registered, if so the fields have to be updated, if not a new user has to be created.
I have tried to implement it in the following way, but this just does not work.

```
public function facebook_add(){

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $User_data = array('User'=>$this->request->data);

        $this->User->email = $User_data['User']['email'];

        if($this->User->exists()){         
                     if($this->User->save($User_data)){ 
                    $message='1';   
                     }else{
                      $errors = $this->User->invalidFields(); 
                       $user_error=array_shift(array_slice($errors, 0, 1));                                   
                       $message= array_shift(array_slice($user_error, 0, 1));
                    }    
        }else{
               if($this->User->save($User_data)){   
                    $message='1';   
                     }else{  
                      $errors = $this->User->invalidFields(); 

                       $user_error=array_shift(array_slice($errors, 0, 1));                                   
                       $message= array_shift(array_slice($user_error, 0, 1));

                    }  
        }
                    $this->set(array(
        'message' => $message,
        '_serialize' => array('message')
    ));                                                 
}      
}
```

The problem is initiating a new user object if there was none user found. Any help to go around it is much appreciated.

Comment: what is the problem exactly? The only thing I can see is thata when your user doen't exists, you should create it frist `$this->User->create()`

Comment: @YerkoPalma, thanks a lot. THat was exactly what I was looking for.
Could you create an answer, so I could mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, when you need to create a `new` record, yout should call `$this->User->create()` before `$this->User->save($User_data)` so the data that you are saving is already initialized.